# How to convert a shape into another shape in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have an illustrator file with many (~40) similar circles (just with different colors) but now I regret having chosen them as circles and want them as triangles instead. Is it possible to do this with Illustrator?

One option is to create lots of triangles and positioning them on top of the circles, individually color them like each circle and removing the circles. But I am wondering if there is a more automatic way to do this

Comment: Needs a programmer (I'm not one), but it's well possible that he has already worked it out. Check, if this link contains something usable. https://astutegraphics.com/blog/30-must-free-illustrator-scripts-2/ At least one of these seems to search and replace shapes. If you read, speak and write well Illustrator's scripting language, you can modify something existing to handle more than one exact shape form or color at a time.

Comment: [Possibly a duplicate](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/114144/63979)... Check my answer there, I provided a solution for your problem.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as I want to preserve the color and stroke of each original shape. I think @Danielillo's answer does that very well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what kind of triangles are needed.

An easy way with Illustrator's tools is:

A circle has four vector points, it's necessary to have only three.

- Select all the circles
- Go to menu **Object** → **Path** → **Add anchor points** (to get 8 points)
- Go to menu **Object** → **Path** → **Simplify** and move the slider until get just three points per shape
- Use the **Direct Selection Tool** to select the half of the vector points and press the **Convert to Smooth** icon and the **Convert to Corner** icon
- Do the same with the other half

[image]

- Select the triangles and go to menu **Effect** → **Distort &
  Transform** → **Transform**, rotate and scale until get the desire
  triangle shape

[image]

- Expand Appearance to get the triangle's vector points

[image: triangles]

Comment: Ah affine transforms to the rescue.